# How many times do variations of "halachta b'drachav" appear in the Chumash, and why?

Tags: parshanut-torah-comment

The past few weeks, the phrase "halachta b'drachav" or "Lalechet B'drachav" or "Lalechet b'chol drachav" meaning  "walk in His ways" (or "walk in ways that are proper before Him" according to Onkelos) appears numerous times. Some examples include:

> וְהָלַכְתָּ, בִּדְרָכָיו (Devarim, 28:9)

> לָלֶכֶת בְּכָל-דְּרָכָיו (Devarim 10:12)

> לָלֶכֶת בִּדְרָכָיו, (Devarim 8:6)

I purposefully pulled this quote three times with three different ways of the Torah writing it (all with the same basic translation as perk Onkelos) because that is part of my question (which admittedly has multiple parts). My questions include:

- How many times in Chumash does this phrase (the way it's written doesn't matter, just the idea) appear?
- Why are they written differently, (see the pesukim attached)
- Are there any sources on why it's written so many times (is there something we can learn from it)?

Comment: In the chumash, I count 8, all in Devarim (8:6, 10:12, 11:22, 19:9, 26:17, 28:9, 30:16, 32:4). Another 30+ in Nach.

Comment: Do you know of any reason given why it would appear these 8 times?

Comment: interestingly enoguh, i went through those 8. the first 7 have the same translation by Onkelos, the last one is not a command to walk in HaShem's ways but a description of HaShem's ways. So, perhaps the count is 7.

Comment: Interestingly, the Rambam in Mitzvah 8, mentions that the Torah repeats this a few times and doesn’t seem to be bothered by it. Furthermore, he himself brings one of the pesukim for the mitzvah and then quotes a gemara in Sota 14a that actually uses a different passuk for this.

Comment: See Chofetz Chaim (I think, *al ha'torah*), *parshas Ekev*.

Comment: Rav Asher Weiss [briefly discussed this](https://minchasasher.com/shiur/parsha-shiurim/vhalachta-bdrachav/)